# AutoComplete TextBox with SQL LIKE operator

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have an AutoComplete `TextBox` in a Desktop application where it is populating the list from a Sql DataBase.
When typing, it is filtering only starting with the first character.
How could I provide an option to search in the middle or 1st or any character of the AutoComplete text as a `LIKE` operator?

This is my code (not working):

```vb
Private Sub OrderNoTextBox_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrderNoTextBox.Click

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(cnn)
    connection.Open()

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.[Order].OrderNo FROM dbo.[Order] INNER JOIN dbo.BatchInformation ON dbo.[Order].OrderID = dbo.BatchInformation.OrderID GROUP BY dbo.[Order].OrderNo HAVING dbo.[Order].OrderNo LIKE '%" & Trim(OrderNoTextBox.Text) & "%' ", connection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim list As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

    While reader.Read
        If reader.IsDBNull(0) = False Then
            list.Add(reader.Item("OrderNo"))
        End If
    End While

    reader.Close()

    OrderNoTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    OrderNoTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    OrderNoTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = list

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems to make a partial search using OrderNoTextBox.Text content. Normally this can be be traumatic  for the database, since no normal index can be used. Do you want to search based on substrings of OrderNoTextBox.Text?

Comment: yes,I want to search based on substrings of OrderNoTextBox.Text

Comment: It does not make too much sense to allow searches based on substrings. Maybe you want to perform the search for every `OrderNoTextBox.Text` change.

Comment: I want to this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1so812vdlpbf6q/22.png?dl=0